# What's the difference between ftrace and blktrace tracepoints?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, ftrace

For instance, we have `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_bio_complete` and `block_rq_complete` which is basically IO completion trace points for `ftrace`, I believe. Using `sudo blktrace -d /dev/sdb1 -o - | blkparse -i -` we might see a line like this:

```
  8,33   1        3     0.001086286     0  C  RA 1158137880 + 8 [0]
                                           ^ IO completion action
```

The `C` here is the IO completion event according to the documentation but is this the same as `block_bio_complete` or is it somehow different. Checking the source code, I can see at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/block/blk-core.c#L1441:

```
trace_block_rq_complete(req, blk_status_to_errno(error), nr_bytes);
```

And at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/block/bio.c#L1863:

```
trace_block_bio_complete(bio->bi_disk->queue, bio, blk_status_to_errno(bio->bi_status));
```

Which of the two is the `C` action? Or does `blktrace` use a separate set of actions - searches tell me `ftrace` and `blktrace` use different reporting mechanisms, but I cannot work out how each tracepoint for both mechanisms relate to kernel source code. Is there an easy way to map tracepoints to source code?